# How to make forms and add data for 4 nested one-to-many relationships in Django?

Tags: jquery, mysql, django

I have 4 models: Corporation, Division, Store and Section. Corporation has one or many divisions, division has one or many stores and store has one or many sections.
I need to make a html which will allow adding corporation, then many divisions for that corporation and for every division possibility to add stores and so on. That has to be on the same page. For every model there needs to be add button which will open form for adding desired object and delete button which will remove object if user changes its mind. If user clicks 'add store', form for store will show up inside division in which store needs to be added.
I don't know how to manage that and organize forms and how to pack data back through POST nor how to unpack it and save into database.

I have tried manually making all fields that I need on html and not bounding it to any django form and packing all data in json, then sending it through ajax, but it's very tiresome and ugly, because I have to pack four level nested json and do the unpacking on the back and again manually save every object.

Comment: It may be worth your time to complete the official Django tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/). It really helped me understand how forms, models, views, all work together with Django.

Comment: I read the tutorial when I started working on the app and when there was no so many nested models. I used inline django forms and it woked fine, but now I don't even know where to start. I need dynamically added field because I don't know how many instances will there be when I add store in division, for example. I tried so many things, but it gets to complicated for me to know how to work with it or manage it. Thanks anyway! I'll try reading it one more time.